# How to testfor @p except for a certain

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to use a command that will testfor @p but exclude a specific player. This is the command I tried but it does not function:

```
/testfor @p[r=3,!name=name here]
```

The commands need to function with version 1.12.2

Answer (score 0):

It's `name=!Horst` for a player "Horst".

Comment: I That tried that, but it just says can't find entity.

Comment: Is there a player online that is **not** called the name in your command?

Comment: If I enter `/say abc @p[name=!FaRo1] def`, I get "abc  def", so it should work. Are you sure that the player(s) that you want to find is in a radius of 3 blocks?

Answer (score 0):

You got close.  The exclamation point goes after the equals sign in the target selector.  The fixed command is:

```
/testfor @p[r=3,name=!<name>]
```

I imagine the reason you got a down vote is because this question has an easy to obtain answer.  [Here is the wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#Selecting_targets_by_name) on the subject.  The page is actually the wiki on all Minecraft commands and can be very useful when working with commands.

Comment: Yes, I know It's an easy to obtain answer, but for some reason it dosen't work.

Comment: What is not working about it?  What are you attempting to do with it?  How are you executing it?  I only ask because, as is, the command is not all that useful.